# What happens (from the first principle perspective) when you connect 2 negative terminals in a DC Circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, batteries

[image: This is the diagram]

E is the electromotive force, r is the internal resistance.

Comment: This happens many times every day: battery chargers! Automotive jumper cables!

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically the current will be $I=\frac{E_2-E_1}{r_1+r_2}$ If the two sources are identical there will be no current.  Otherwise the source with the higher emf will determine the direction of the current through the circuit.

Answer (score -2):

Theoretically there will be no current in the circuit.  Every battery has an internal resistance which is huge in reverse direction. If potential difference of one cell is greater than the other there will be a trickle of current maybe.

Comment: Re, " internal resistance...is huge in reverse direction." Where did you read that? How do you think battery chargers work?

Comment: Batteries are not rechargeable and offer immense resistance if they are connected in reverse.  What you are talking about are  called "rechargeable batteries".  I am not sure if there is a new symbol for them in electronic circuits.

Comment: All batteries are rechargeable in principle. The main problem is a practical one: The chemical reaction that provides the power also compromises the physical structure of the battery. That's why even "rechargeable" batteries don't last forever. In some of the classic "wet" cells from the 19-th century, the electrodes literally disintegrated as the battery was used up. You can't recharge that; but the disposable "dry-cell" batteries that you can buy just about anywhere, Those can re-charged maybe five or ten times, if you do it right, before the case ruptures and the caustic goo leaks out.